# ToolBar its not full

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I have a layout with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <com.rbrlnx.cover.GroupSummaryCoverView
                    android:layout_below="@id/action_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/group_summary_cover_view"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/group_info_title_view"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/group_detail_components_lateral_margin"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/group_detail_components_lateral_margin"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/group_detail_components_lateral_margin"/>

        <View android:id="@+id/name_setting_divider"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/space_medium"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              style="@style/group_detail_list_top_divider"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/lv_participants"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

What's wrong? As you can see the ToolBar its not completly shown.

Comment: Do you plan to have a transparent statusbar? If not I would suggest to remove all the `fitsSystemWindows` attributes.

Comment: Ok, i just copied some examples from internet and it was in all of them. I will remove.

Comment: Thats it, thanks. Its solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fitsSystemWindows`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) attribute is used to draw a View on the whole screen, including the area of the statusbar. It's usually used to draw a custom background behind the statusbar when it's transparent.

Since you are not using a transparent statusbar, you can easily remove all `fitsSystemWindows` attributes from your layout. So the Views won't be hidden behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to paste this in your `styles.xml` file from `values-v21` directory:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```